# Exception in variables formatting using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

i am trying to implement the below code in my app, but an exception is thrown. I need to extract year, month, day from a date and pass them to a predicate. The exception is at line:

```
NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear == %@", yearBuscado];
```

And here is the full method code:

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
    {
      if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription *entity = 
                   [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteThing" 
                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

      [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

      NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
                  [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" 
                                              ascending:YES];

      NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
                                  initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        //SOLO TO-DOS DE TODAY


        todayDate = [NSDate date];

        NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:todayDate]; // Get necessary date components

        NSString *yearStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[components year]];
        NSString *monthStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[components month]];
        NSString *dayStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[components day]];
        NSString *hourStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) [components hour]];
        NSString *minuteStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) [components minute]];


        NSNumber *yearBuscado = (long)[components year];
        NSNumber *mesBuscado = (long) [components month];
        NSNumber *diaBuscado = (long) [components year];
        NSString *tipourgente = @"Urgent";
        NSString *tipocolor = @"Yellow";
        NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear == %@", yearBuscado];
        NSPredicate *monthPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoMonth == %@", mesBuscado];
        NSPredicate *dayPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoDay == %@", diaBuscado];
        NSPredicate *urgentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urgent == %@", tipourgente];
        NSPredicate *colorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@", tipocolor];

      [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];






      NSPredicate *busqueda = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[yearPredicate, monthPredicate,dayPredicate,urgentPredicate]];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:busqueda];
      NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
                  [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                      managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
      aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
      [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];


      [aFetchedResultsController release];
      [fetchRequest release];
      [sortDescriptor release];
      [sortDescriptors release];


      return fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
NSNumber *yearBuscado = (long)[components year];
```

as `[components year]` returns an integer, and not a `NSNumber` object.
It should be

```
NSNumber *yearBuscado = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[components year]];
```

or better, using the new  syntax for "boxed expressions":

```
NSNumber *yearBuscado = @([components year]);
```

*Alternatively,* use

```
NSInteger yearBuscado = [components year];
```

and change your predicate to

```
NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear == %ld", (long)yearBuscado];
```

Comment: That is, thank you very much for your time and for answering so clearly...thank you

Comment: If i use your NSPredicate proposal, there are no results shown...I have keep my NSPredicate version:  NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear == %@", yearBuscado]; and it is working as expected. Thank you in any case, your first part of the answer is working as I needed.